# Plural of Quorum or synonym thereof

Tags: grammatical-number, synonyms, latin

I am writing some APIs and documentation. We have configurable "voting rules" which are methods for deciding when a business process may proceed.

Some examples:

- First valid response
- Majority Super
- Majority but requires minimum participation

Users may actually create their own voting logic and configure our system to use it. So, I decided to call this voting logic module a "quorum". That left me with reaching for the plural of quorum which (I believe) to be "qui".

Feedback has come to me that this is too obscure. The academic in me would insist that the great unwashed masses wash themselves and learn something (a new word) but I also believe the word "quorum" is truly the most accurate word to describe these logic modules and thus the plural should be "qui".

My questions to the community:

- Is the word "quorum" appropriate here?
- If so, is "qui" the correct plural?
- If not, then what is a more appropriate?
- Even if everything I say is correct is there a more approachable and also accurate term?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have it backwards.

"quorum" is actually genitive **plural of** "qui" in Latin.

In English the plural of "quorum" is "quorums", with English regular pluralization rules.

Oxford Dictionaries (I don't want to confuse this with OED) says the definition of quorum is:

> The minimum number of members of an assembly or society that must be present at any of its meetings to make the proceedings of that meeting valid.

Comment: How about a more approachable synonym? I am not sure reversing things would calm my critics :)

Comment: I'm trying to think of that.

Comment: I changed my documentation to be quorum and it didn't seem to raise any more eyebrows; maybe that's good enough. Thanks.

Comment: Good common sense.  If in doubt, avoid.  Too few people know enough Latin to be bothered by the finer points of a Latin tag that is a virtual noun formed from the genitive masculine plural of a relative pronoun.  Should the number required for a meeting of Women's Aid be called a 'quarum' (the feminine version of 'quorum') rather than a 'quorum'?  Surely not.  To me 'quorums' sounds awkward, but that is because I'm familiar with Latin.  I am beginning to get over my dislike of the clash, as ought to have done long ago.

Answer (score -5):

The plural of quorum should be **quora**. Latin plural for a masculine noun ending in -um.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. This answer needs corroboration, I'm afraid. If *quorum* was a Latin noun, it would be neuter (which would indeed have an *-a* plural form), but it's actually the genitive plural of *qui,* explained by OED as "from the wording of commissions in which certain persons were specially designated as members of a body by the words *quorum vos...unum* (*duos,* etc.) *esse volumus,* ‘of whom we will that you..be one (two, etc.)’."

Comment: [Merriam-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quorum) allows "quora" as well as "quorums", although I'm sure some pedants would object. But Merriam-Webster doesn't like pedants. And since it doesn't have the same meaning in Latin, and isn't even the same part of speech, it's reasonable for it to have a different plural (c.f. agendas, etc.)

Comment: @StuartF, sure 'it's reasonable for it to have a different plural', but that should then be the plain English one, *quorums*, rather than the pseudo-Latin *quora*. (Your comment leaves an impression that you are defending *quora*, but it is not entirely clear whether that was your intention.)

Comment: I appreciate the timely followup. The question was posted over 7 years ago :)